# Multiple database trigger on insert

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

having some trouble creating a trigger across databases.

I am doing this query through phpmyadmin.

If I put the following through, I get an error saying no database selected.

```
delimiter // 
DROP trigger if exists t1// 
CREATE trigger t1 AFTER INSERT ON db1.d1t
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERT INTO db2.d2t SET ID=NEW.ID;

END// 
delimiter ;
```

If I navigate to db1 in Phpmyadmin and then do the following:

```
delimiter // 
DROP trigger if exists t1// 
CREATE trigger t1 AFTER INSERT ON db1t
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERT INTO db2.db2t SET ID=NEW.ID;

END// 
delimiter ;
```

There trigger is created but it is trying to insert on `db1.db2.db2t` When it fires.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:
Both Tables are INNODB
mysql server v. 5.1.61
phpmyadmin   v. 3.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (**EDITED**):

```
USE db1;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS t1;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER t1 AFTER INSERT ON d1t
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO db2.d2t
    (ID)
  VALUES
    (NEW.ID);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

This is working for me.

Comment: I have had a play with this and I am getting USE is not allowed in stored procedures.

Comment: @Zac Right yeh I'm getting the same message, but the above is working for me.

Comment: Yeah, just got that too. You have to be outside of a DB and then use the `USE DB` and then simply `db2.t` in the insert. Many thanks for your help. this must be a phpmyadmin bug of setting triggers within a db. Many thanks for your time.